# Split N elements into different columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, split

I have this issue I am trying to solve. I have a column that can includes multiple value in each cell. Values are separated by comma. Is there a dynamic way in pandas to split only first 3 values into 3 different columns while keeping the main column changed.

Input Table:

```
    Phone Number
    233,234,235,236,237,223
    214,226,290
    230,231,228,290,221
```

```
Output Table:
Phone Number                  Phone Number 1 Phone Number 2  Phone Number 3
233,234,235,236,237,223       233            234             235
214,226,290                   214,           226,            290
230,231                       230,           231
```

I need to create the columns in a for loop so the creation of the columns would be dynamic if possible.

Comment: While keeping the main column changed or unchanged ?

Comment: While keeping the main column unchanged

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and slicing:

```
N = 3

df[[f'Phone Number {x+1}' for x in range(N)]] = (
    df['Phone Number'].str.split(',', n=N+1, expand=True).iloc[:, :N]
)
```

Output:

```
              Phone Number Phone Number 1 Phone Number 2 Phone Number 3
0  233,234,235,236,237,223            233            234            235
1              214,226,290            214            226            290
2      230,231,228,290,221            230            231            228
```

Other example:

```
              Phone Number Phone Number 1 Phone Number 2 Phone Number 3
0  233,234,235,236,237,223            233            234            235
1              214,226,290            214            226            290
2                  230,231            230            231           None
```

Comment: Thanks mozway for the answer. I was wondering if I have another column in the same dataframe that I would like to apply same logic to. Is there a way to make it dynamic as well without adding the name of column everytime?

Comment: If you wrap it in a simple loop this might be the easiest, how many columns do you have on which you want to apply? Can you extend your question with an extra example?